# Wordpress - New posts have stopped showing

Tags: wordpress

I have weird problem with display new posts. Before I made this topic, i try to found answer in google and fix it. Now I write, what i do to this time:

- Turn on/off every plugins. Still doesnt display new posts.
- Change permalinks (using post name), so i change to plain and back to post name. Still doesnt display new posts.
- I try to reset permalinks, clicked 'save changes'. Still doesnt display new posts.
- .htaccess permissions (now i have 644, tried to changed to 666). Still doesnt display new posts.
- I havent made any changes in code, just when i want to add new post, this one not show at website. When i click in admin panel to the link, its works fine. I can show you the code, but i think problem is in the other place. Maybe something with .htaccess or host server?

Here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

## Default .htaccess file

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^logowanie /wp-login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

#AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
#AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

<files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

Comment: jus check, wheather you marked them as schedule, check your site time, if current time is future time, automatically it will go to scheduled posts

Comment: i checked this, and everything is correct. Any other ideas?

Comment: Does the single post permalink work? Try the following: 1> use the default theme; 2> disable plugins one by one, to narrow down the cause.

Answer (score 0):

well clear the casche

take a backup and restore somewhere else to see if is problem of hosting company

try to use another theme for testing

maybe someone had hacked your site

BEST SOLUTION IS
++++++++++++++++++++

if you have a good backup before the apperance of the problem just restore it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what was the reason, but i resolved when i removed posts in database. Sound weird but working. Anyway, maybe is only my imagination and the problem is in the other place.